# Dockerizing a react app for production does not work as expected in combination with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Long story short, I have 2 images. One is for the client and the other one is for the server. I am using docker-compose and when I was running everything in development mode everything was working as expected and I could access my app.

I had this line `"proxy": "http://server:5000"` in package-json and it was working as expected.

I didn't change anything in my docker-compose file which is here:

```js
version: "3.8"
services:
  server:
    image: "srdjano1/reaction-server"
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    env_file:
      - ./.env

  client:
    image: "srdjano1/reaction-client-prod"
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

However, when I  want to launch my React app in production mode and add `nginx` , now requests are no longer received by server.

Here is the new Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Does someone know the reason for this?

Comment: Have you pointed your nginx to port 5000 or is it defaulting to 80 if so then you need to change the 5000:5000 to 80:5000

Comment: I've changed 80:5000 in my server config , but then I need to change client to `3000:80` as I can't have the same host port. Anyhow, still the same issue.

I am not sure how to point `nginx` to port 5000

Comment: You can use nginx manager to ease that process pull the docker image down and play around with it and see if this might help your situation

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://nginxproxymanager.com/ this is a open source manager for nginx that has a GUI interface. It might help to solve the port issues at it makes it very easy to apply without complicated config setups